# Fitting a ImageView half the screen height and full the screen width

Tags: java, android, xml, image, resize

How it is : http://i49.tinypic.com/352lxdt.png
How I want : http://i45.tinypic.com/bahc1.png

how to do this via XML and also via code.?
I am using RelativeLayout.
also want API level 8 (from android 2.3+)..
so cant use setWidth(), setHeight()
help..?

Comment: What restricting you from using setWidth() and setHeight() ?

Comment: Could you add the code you are using now ? That makes it easier for us to comment on what you could change

Comment: @ndsmyter http://pastebin.com/Ev2KyZBj

Comment: @android.fryo i cant coz setwidth() and setheight() requires api level 11 and i want backwards compability for api level 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout that has a weight sum, and give  the RelativeLayout the weight you want. example:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</LinearLayout>
```